# Copy specified elements and children and attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

Given the following XML:

```
<Products>
    <Batteries>
        <Name Value="Triple A"/>
        <Colour Value="Red"/>
    </Batteries>
    <Cups>
        <Name Value="Mugs"/>
        <Colour Value="Blue"/>
        <Logo>
            <Company Value="Super Clean!"/>
            <Colour Value="Red"/>
        </Logo>
    </Cups>
    <Cups>
        <Name Value="Teacups"/>
        <Colour Value="Orange"/>
        <Handle Value="Dainty"/>
        <Logo>
            <Company Value="Lovely teas"/>
            <Colour Value="Red"/>
        </Logo>
    </Cups>
</Products>
```

How would I copy the `Cups` elements and all their child elements *and* all their attributes? The descendants of `Cups` could be virtually anything (e.g. a new element may be added and I still want it copied), and they may have additional attributes as well.

So my required output in this case is:

```
<Products>
    <Cups>
        <Name Value="Mugs"/>
        <Colour Value="Blue"/>
        <Logo>
            <Company Value="Super Clean!"/>
            <Colour Value="Red"/>
        </Logo>
    </Cups>
    <Cups>
        <Name Value="Teacups"/>
        <Colour Value="Orange"/>
        <Handle Value="Dainty"/>
        <Logo>
            <Company Value="Lovely teas"/>
            <Colour Value="Red"/>
        </Logo>
    </Cups>
</Products>
```

After some flailing around I've got this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Products>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Products>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Cups|Cups//*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it isn't copying across the attributes to the output.

Note: This isn't my XML and there's no schema for it, but I'm really sure there will be `Cups`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this template....

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This will ignore all attributes and text nodes (and elements that haven't been matched by your other template).

What you could do, is simply change your template matching "Cups|Cups//*" to use `xsl:copy-of` instead...

```
<xsl:template match="Cups">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

However, it looks what you are really trying to do is actually remove the `Batteries` node and its descendants. If so, use the identity template to copy everything else, and just have single template to ignore `Batteries`, like so...

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Batteries" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: In response to your comment, if the elements you wish to copy are in the minority, try this approach instead...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Products/*" />

    <xsl:template match="Cups|Spoons" priority="2">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will remove all elements under `Products` with the exception of `Cups` and `Spoons`.

Comment: Your updated and very correct `Cups` matching template did the job! I can't really do a template to remove `Batteries` as my very contrived example didn't convey that in my actual XML there are many, varied other elements and the elements I want to copy are in the minority - but your answer fits the bill perfectly. Many thanks! Kicking myself for not realising that myself :)

Comment: If it helps, I've expanded my answer to show a slightly different approach for the case where the elements you wish to copy being in the minority.

Comment: That's very helpful, I wish I could upvote multiple times!